# PHP: Tomar valor de un arreglo dentro de un while y mandarlo a otra pagina

Tags: php, array, while

Tengo un problema. Necesito ayuda para recorrer un while y tomar el valor de un arreglo que está lleno de datos de una base de datos. Necesito tomar cierto valor y mandar los datos de ese arreglo a otra página.

Dejo aquí mi código:

```
<?php while($row = $execute->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
    <tbody>
        <form class="" action="promotor registro general detalles.php" method="post">
            <tr>
                <td> <?php echo $row['fecha']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo $row['entrada']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo $row['salida']; ?></td>
                <td> <input type="submit" name="detalles" value="Detalles"></td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </tbody>
<?php } ?>
```

Lo que específicamente necesito es saber como, al pulsar el botón detalles, se tome el registro de ese botón.

Tengo una idea de usar el $`_SESSION`, pero no se como darle el valor especifico de ese registro.

Espero haber sido especifico.

Comment: Si `$row` tiene un campo `id` puedes poner ese id como query string en el `action` de tu formulario, o bien ponerlo en un input de tipo hidden dentro de éste.

Comment: La primera parte de  la consulta se entiende que quieres mandar los datos del arreglo a otra página pero la última parte dices que 'Se tome el registro de ese botón' , te refieres que al pulsar el botón detalles  luego ¿envié el registro o sea los valores del arreglo a otra página?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me imagino que esos datos que nos dices deben de tener una id lo que debes hacer es poner esa id como variable en tu url asi:

```
<?php while($row = $execute->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
    <tbody>
        <form class="" action="promotor registro general detalles.php?var1=<?php echo $row['id_del_registro']; ?>" method="post">
            <tr>
                <td> <?php echo $row['fecha']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo $row['entrada']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo $row['salida']; ?></td>
                <td> <input type="submit" name="detalles" value="Detalles"></td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </tbody>
<?php } ?>
```

Luego en tu archivo detalles.php lo recibes asi

```
$id = $_GET["var1"];
```

Ya puedes hacer tu consulta con esa id para traer todos los datos que necesitas para tu detalle

Answer (score 2):

La manera mas fácil es mandar el identificador del registro por `GET` a la otra página mediante el uso de un `href` de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php while($row = $execute->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td> <?php echo $row['fecha']; ?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row['entrada']; ?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row['salida']; ?></td>
        //Aquí utilizas el id del registro para identificarlo
        <td><a href="promotor registro general detalles.php?id_registro=<?php echo $row['salida']; ?>" role="button">Detalles</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<?php } ?>
```

En tu archivo *promotor registro general detalles.php*, lo recibes de la siguiente manera:

```
$id = $_GET['id_registro'];
```

Ya con esto puedes realizar lo que desees con el registro seleccionado.

Comment: O sea, ¿en lugar de usar el metodo POST del form, uso el get en href?

Comment: Asi es, ya que solo lo que interesa saber es el id para despues hacer la consulta del detalle

Comment: Muchas gracias! me ayudó mucho! surgió otro problema, pero por el editor jaja, muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada para eso esta la comunidad, si te sirvio marca la respuesta como aceptada.